# Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server: "Column 'volume' cannot be null"

Tags: java, sql

i hav written a code with getmethod and set method but in the console it says that Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server:

> *"Column 'volume' cannot be null"*

and only getmethod is executed  why not setmethod?

```
 package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo.Packages;
 import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

  public class PackageServicesDAO {

private Connection connection;

public PackageServicesDAO() {
    // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
    connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

}

public List<Packages> get_all_data() {
    List<Packages> packagesList = new ArrayList<Packages>();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_package_master";
    try {
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Packages pack = new Packages();
            pack.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            pack.setVolume(resultSet.getString("volume"));
            pack.setUnit_type(resultSet.getString("unit_type"));
            pack.setQuantity_in_box(resultSet.getInt("quantity_in_box"));
            pack.setType(resultSet.getString("type"));
            packagesList.add(pack);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return packagesList;
    } 

    public boolean set_all_data() {
        Packages packages = new Packages();
        boolean result = true;
            try {
             PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO spl_package_master(volume,unit_type,quantity_in_box,type)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
             stmt.setString(1, packages.getVolume());
             stmt.setString(2, packages.getUnit_type());
             stmt.setInt(3, packages.getQuantity_in_box());
             stmt.setString(4, packages.getType());


             result = stmt.execute();


        } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
        }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    PackageServicesDAO pac = new PackageServicesDAO();
    List<Packages> data = pac.get_all_data();
    boolean data1 = pac.set_all_data();
    pac.setVolume("450");
    pac.setUnitType("ml");
    pac.setQuantity_in_box("25");
    pac.setType("glass");
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(data1);
    System.exit(0);
   }

   private void setType(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   private void setQuantity_in_box(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

    private void setUnitType(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

    private void setVolume(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

the package class is
package com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo;

```
   public class Packages {

private int  id;

    private String  volume;

    private String  unit_type;

    private int  quantity_in_box;

    private String  type;


    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }

   public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

   public String getVolume() {
    return volume;
   }

  public void setVolume(String volume) {
   this.volume = volume;
    }

  public String getUnit_type() {
  return unit_type;
    }

  public void setUnit_type(String unit_type) {
  this.unit_type = unit_type;
  }

  public int getQuantity_in_box() {
  return quantity_in_box;
  }

   public void setQuantity_in_box(int quantity_in_box) {
  this.quantity_in_box = quantity_in_box;
   }

  public String getType() {
  return type;
   }

   public void setType(String type) {
  this.type = type;
    }


    @Override
   public String toString() {
  return "Packages [id=" + id + ",volume=" + volume + ", unit_type=" + unit_type + ",     quantity_in_box=" + quantity_in_box
          + ", type=" + type + " ]";
        }



      }
```

i hav modified my class but it gives me the output in the console but values written in  setmethod cannot be inserted in to the database table

```
    package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo.Packages;
    import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

    public class PackageServicesDAO {

private Connection connection;

public PackageServicesDAO() {
    // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
    connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

}

public List<Packages> get_all_data() {
    List<Packages> packagesList = new ArrayList<Packages>();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_package_master";
    try {
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Packages pack = new Packages();
            pack.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            pack.setVolume(resultSet.getString("volume"));
            pack.setUnit_type(resultSet.getString("unit_type"));
            pack.setQuantity_in_box(resultSet.getInt("quantity_in_box"));
            pack.setType(resultSet.getString("type"));
            packagesList.add(pack);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return packagesList;
    } 

    public Packages set_all_data() {
        Packages packages = new Packages();
        try {
             PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO spl_package_master(id,volume,unit_type,quantity_in_box,type)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
             stmt.setInt(1, packages.getId());
             stmt.setString(2, packages.getVolume());
             stmt.setString(3, packages.getUnit_type());
             stmt.setInt(4, packages.getQuantity_in_box());
             stmt.setString(5, packages.getType());
             packages.setId(13);
             packages.setVolume("450");
             packages.setUnit_type("ml");
             packages.setQuantity_in_box(25);
             packages.setType("glass");

        } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return packages;
        }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    PackageServicesDAO pac = new PackageServicesDAO();
    List<Packages> data = pac.get_all_data();
    Packages data1 = pac.set_all_data();

    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(data1);
    System.exit(0);
          }
           }
```

Comment: The default constructor in `Packages` does not set the volume to a non null value.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling set method before initializing the properties

```
boolean data1 = pac.set_all_data();
//and after you set properties which are never used.
pac.setVolume("450");
pac.setUnitType("ml");
pac.setQuantity_in_box("25");
pac.setType("glass");
```

Try to set these in Packages constructor

```
Packages packages = new Packages(); // packeges object has properties not initialized I guess
```

For example:

```
Packages packages = new Packages("450", "ml", "25", "glass"); // and set these in constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

It throw the exception due to values are not set in object before insert in D.B

```
  public boolean set_all_data() {
        Packages packages = new Packages();
        boolean result = true;
            try {
             PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO spl_package_master(volume,unit_type,quantity_in_box,type)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
             stmt.setString(1, packages.getVolume());
             stmt.setString(2, packages.getUnit_type());
             stmt.setInt(3, packages.getQuantity_in_box());
             stmt.setString(4, packages.getType());


             result = stmt.execute();


        }
```

Here you are created new instance of 'Packages' and not setting any value.Now all the get methods in Package class is null. Then you inserting it into D.B. In D.B you have declared 'volume' field as not null. you need to set value in the package instance inside method before you going to inserting it into D.B.

Answer (score 0):

In `set_all_data()` your are inserting an emtpy `Packages` with no data setted (this is the cause you are getting a "Column 'volume' cannot be null").
Set `packages` data with setters or using constructor.